# Ribbonコントロールに動的にボタンを追加したい

Tags: vb.net, excel

はじめまして、

VisualStudio2010（VB.NET FrameWork4.0）MicrosoftOffice2007の組み合わせでExcelアドインを作成しています。

リボンコントロール（`Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonGroup`）に対して、を不特定の数のボタン（`Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton`）を動的に追加して必要に応じて消去したいのですが上手くいきません。

http://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/control/buttonarray.html
上記サイトを参考にしてみたのですがMSNによるとRibbonButtonはクラスではなくインターフェースになっておりNewが出来ませんでした。

Ribbon1.Desinger.vbを開いてみると、

```
Friend WithEvents Button2 As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton
```

で定義をして

```
Me.Group1.Items.Add(Me.Button2)
```

でリボンのグループに追加しているように見えました。

そこでリボン上に配置したボタンのイベントに

```
Dim button03 As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton
button03 = Me.Factory.CreateRibbonButton
button03.Label = "リ・ボーン"
Me.Group1.Items.Add(button03)
```

と書いた所、`Item.Add`の所で「コレクションは読み取り専用です。」とエラーが出てしまいます。

自分の書いたサンプルはそもそも動的に不特定の数のボタンを追加する仕様ではありませんがまずは1個でも追加できないかと思い書いてみたのですが果たせませんでした。

どなたかご存知の方おられましたらお助けいただけますでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSTOのリボンには[読み取り専用になるプロパティ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-JP/library/vs/alm/bb608623(v=vs.100).aspx#ReadOnlyProperties)がいくつか存在します。`Items`自体は記載されていませんが、`Groups`や`Tabs`などの他のコレクションプロパティが指定されているので同様の仕様なのだと思われます。

なのでボタンイベントに応じて項目を増減させたい場合、ボタンの追加は諦めてリンク先に記載のある`Dynamic`プロパティを`True`に設定した`RibbonMenu`で妥協するしかないと思われます。

またボタンの追加タイミングが起動時だけでよいのであれば`Ribbon1`のコンストラクターではまだ読み取り専用となっていないので変更が可能です。

```
' 以下のコードをRibbon1.designer.vbからRibbon1.vbに移動する
Public Sub New()

    MyBase.New(Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory())
    InitializeComponent()

    ' TODO:メニューの変更を追加する

End Sub
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。動的な項目追加に関して制限がある旨理解いたしました。ボタンの追加に関しては、アドインで生成したフォームがエクセルのワークシートを選択した結果などで非アクティブになった場合Windows10ではタスクバーでは非アクティブなフォームの存在がわかりづらい為、その通知のためにウィンドウのアイコンイメージを表示したボタンを使おうと考えておりました。　その為生成のタイミングはコンストラクターでは足りないのですがとりあえず難しいということが分かり大変たすかりました。　ありがとうございます。